# expression engine and code igniter to use same system folder

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm trying to get expression engine and code igniter to use the same 'system folder'.
I have both latest versions

- 'Code Igniter 2.1.2' and
- 'Expression Engine 2.5.3'.

The issue i'm seeing is that both 'system's folder have quite major differences where as

- Code Igniter specifically states it's using  CI VERSION 2.1.2 while
- Expression Engine is using CI VERSION 2.0.1

Has anyone been through this and found a way to use a compromise of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each EE release make certain assumptions about the version of CI it will run - the two cannot be altered independently of each other. So I'd either run your CI apps using the EE-supplied CI install, or maintain a separate CI install for them.

Comment: That makes sense, I stupidly was trying the other way around, getting EE to use code igniter's